# need meta viewport settings for iphone - displaying full page width on screen

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, viewport, meta

We are disabling responsiveness. Content width 960px. Everything is working fine but....

My client likes to see the webpage partly on iPhone, on startup. But it's displaying the full page (in width) on the screen.

On my Nokia smartphone (Opera and IE browser) it's displaying correctly, displaying one third of the page.

So please help me for the appropriate viewport settings.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
```